# margin-bottom a bit of a cross browser grey area

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, margin

When i use margin-bottom is CSS, the results vary across browsers (esp lovely IE) what impacts the CSS property "Margin" what other rules do i need to check i've implemented before i can see a consistent result across all browsers...

Comment: What is your question? Is it about CSS Browser compatibility? Check out this reference by quirksmode: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Comment: if you want IE compatibility, you should really check every single thing ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some browsers (IE) collapse margins.  It doesn't just affect the bottom margin, but also the top.

If you have two stacked elements, both with a margin of `margin: 10px 0 15px;`, you might think there would be 25px of space between the two.  However, IE collapses the margins so all that's left is the greatest margin (which is 15px in the example above).

As to helping ensure browsers display things consistently, a good place to start is a good reset stylesheet (Eric Meyer's or YUI's for example).

Comment: all browsers are supposed to collapse the margins. It's defined within the css spec.

Answer (score 0):

I would look up things like 'ie box model bugs' to understand some of the quirks.  Most times, if you're seeing different margins, it may because the element also has some padding that's being interpreted differently.

But if you can provide more detail, we can elaborate more!